# jquery: Adding code around a html-section(with a id) with no direct editing options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m trying to add some Google Website Optimizer code in front of a section of html and some code after the section. The problem is that I can´t impliment it directly due to that the site is edited in a editor and the options to put in code /edit html is very limited.

I can impliment code/script in the header and on the buttom of the page only.

I want to impliment:

```
<script>utmx_section("Buybutton")</script>
```

In front of:

```
<TABLE ID="BUYSECTION">
<TR>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP">Amount<BR><INPUT ID="amount" TYPE="TEXT" CLASS="TextInputField_ProductInfo" NAME="AMOUNT" SIZE="3" MAXLENGTH="6" VALUE="1"></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD CLASS="BuyButton_ProductInfo">Buy<BR><INPUT TYPE="IMAGE" BORDER="0" SRC="/images/buybutton.png"></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

And the following code right after:

```
</noscript>
```

I have tried with the follow code (jquery) at the buttom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('<script>utmx_section("Buybutton")</script>').insertBefore('#BUYSECTION');
$('</noscript>').insertAfter('#BUYSECTION');
</script>
```

But it do not work...

Do anybody see the error ? / see another solution !?

.

**UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE:**

AlienWebguy helped alot... but its not quite works yet. I tried to fix the code myself from the work AlienWebguy did, but this do not work.

This is what I got so far:

```
<script>
// Create script tag with native JS
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = eval('utmx_section("Buybutton")');

// Add it in front of the html-section with JQuery
$(script).insertBefore('#BUYSECTION');

// Add a </noscript>-end-tag  after the html-section
$('#BUYSECTION').parent().html($('#BUYSECTION').parent().html() + '</noscript>');
</script>
```

It do not make any errors in the chrome console - but it do not validate in Google Website Optimizer.

Do anyone see the error ? -or can figure out an easier solution ?

Thanks in advance!

- Anders

Comment: Is anything showing up in your javascript console (shift-ctrl-J in chrome/firefox)? If this code is causing errors, they'll be logged there.

Comment: I get a: 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){

    // Create script tag with native JS
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.innerHTML = eval('utmx_section("Buybutton")');

    // Add it with JQuery
    $('head').append(script);

    // Wrap table with noscript
    $('#BUYSECTION').wrap('<noscript />');

});
```

EDIT: It wouldn't necessarily immediately follow the table, but this would place the closing noscript tag after the table inside the same container:

```
$('#BUYSECTION').parent().html($('#BUYSECTION').parent().html() + '</noscript>');
```

Comment: Hmm... I still get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"... It looks like it do not "read" the first <script> in the "<script>utmx_section("Buybutton")</script>"-code when I look at the color of the code in chrome SHIFT+CTRL+J.

Comment: This do not make any errors in chrome: SHIFT+CTRL+J but it makes the whole html-section disappear.

Comment: Be aware about that its only a "ending" </noscript>-tag that is allowed.

Comment: <script>utmx_section("Buybutton")</script>  +  HTML-section  +  </noscript>

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+I brings up the console.

Comment: Yes... Your latest answer do the HTML section disappear. I think that the last line of code is wrong: "    $('#BUYSECTION').wrap('<noscript />');" - Because its only a closing </noscript>-tag there is to be there after the html section.

Comment: Yes... but I do not what to wrap a noscript around the html section. Only a end tag after the html section (</noscript>).

Comment: Why only an end tag? Where's the opening tag?

Comment: well... its how Google website optimizer works. <script>utmx_section("Name")</script> + the-text/images/html-you-want-to-change + </noscript>

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=29619&topic=29622&answer=186234#m3